# How do I convert Google Scripts date range strings like "LAST_MONTH" to actual dates?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-api, date-range

Several functions in Google Scripts for Adwords supports the following date range strings:

> TODAY, YESTERDAY, LAST_7_DAYS, THIS_WEEK_SUN_TODAY, LAST_WEEK, LAST_14_DAYS, LAST_30_DAYS, LAST_BUSINESS_WEEK, LAST_WEEK_SUN_SAT, THIS_MONTH, LAST_MONTH, ALL_TIME

One would think that the functions you pass the strings to were able to convert those strings to a start and end date. For instance, **LAST_MONTH** would be converted to start date **2013-02-01** and end date **2013-02-28**, and **TODAY** would be converted to start- and end date **2013-03-01**.

Does Google Scripts also provide a way for users to parse those strings into a start and end date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this same question on Google Groups ([here is the answer.](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/community?place=msg%2Fadwords-scripts%2FDGp5xiKRx3I%2FRb7EAnjfK3IJ)). To summarize, there is no public method for achieving this in Google Scripts, and a custom solution has to be deployed. Since I'm exporting the Adwords data to a personal database anyway I'll be solving this using PHP, so I won't be posting a solution here.

Comment: Well, why not?  Beyond the fact that you could basically lowercase it, replace with underscore with a space and then pass it to `strtotime` given that you're using PHP...

Comment: @Charles Well, `strtotime` converts strings to single points in time, but I need them converted to time spans (a start and end date.)